# How can I use gcloud auth?

Tags: google-cloud-sql, gcloud, google-authentication

I am trying to follow the tutorial of python with google cloud sql.

When I run: `./cloud_sql_proxy -instances="My-connection-name"=tcp:3306`, I get `google: could not find default credentials. See https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/application-default-credentials for more information.`.

Also, when I run: `gcloud auth application-default login`, I get `www.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fcloud-platform&access_type=offline" doesn’t understand the “open location” message. (-1708)`

I followed downloaded the json file for the credintials and set the enviromnet virable `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` to link to the json file, but I still get the same error.

Answer (score 3):

**TL;DR** - You can ignore the `doesn’t understand the “open location” message. (-1708)` error. You should see a browser window/tab opening with the URL, if not you can follow the steps I've added below where you can manually copy-paste the URL in the browser and you should not be seeing any warnings/errors.

You will need to authorize gcloud (one-time step) to use your account credentials for Google Cloud API calls.

1. Run [`gcloud auth application-default login --no-launch-browser`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/application-default/login)
2. You will be provided a URL. Open the URL in the browser, authorize the application using your Google account and you will be provided a verification code in the page.
3. Copy the verification code and paste it back in the terminal where you ran the `gcloud` command in Step 1.

Now gcloud as well as any Google Cloud Client libraries you use can make use of the [Application Default Credentials](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/application-default-credentials) from that machine.